# Data frame creation with dynamically assigned variable names

Tags: r, rlang

I'd like to assign a value to a variable the name of which is determined on the fly, and then assign that variable to a column of a data frame, something like:

```
x = rnorm(10)
y = 'z'
data.frame(assign(y, x))
```

While assign(y, x) creates z with the right values, it fails to name the data frame's column "z".

Comment: Does this work `assign(y, x)`?

Comment: Huh, I'll file this in the "trying too hard" folder.  Thanks!

Comment: If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as such so that you get the credit.

Comment: @Duck - what if I wanted to assign x to a new dataframe with column name of whatever is in y?  data.frame(assign(y, x)) doesn't work for that.

Comment: Let me add as an answer! For a dataframe you can use `!!`

Comment: Once you make the data.frame and assign it to df, you can change the names attribute `names(df) <- y`.

Comment: @Duck - I'm not following how I'd use !!.  I've changed the description of what I'm trying to accomplish - something like data.frame(assign(y, x)) to result in a column data frame with the column name of z

Comment: @rimorob Yeah, I have added a possible solution to what you want! Avoid my suggestion of using `!!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the OP comment, the solution would be:

```
#Code
assign(y, x)
```

For the other issue you can try:

```
#Code2
df <- data.frame(assign(y, x))
names(df)[1] <- y
```

Output:

```
df
            z
1  -0.5611014
2  -2.2370362
3   0.9037152
4  -1.1543826
5   0.4997336
6  -0.4726948
7  -0.6566381
8   1.0173725
9  -0.5230326
10 -0.9362808
```